# Разные сервисы для разных компонентов на Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Имеется компонент `A` и сервис `CountService`. В компоненте две кнопки + и - и текстовое поле. В сервисе имеется переменная `count` типа `number`. При нажатии кнопки плюс на компоненте, переменная в сервисе увеличивается на 1, при нажатии на минус уменьшается и передается в `Subject`. Компонент подписан на изменение `count` и при изменении выводит ее в текстовое поле.

[Сам код на plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/XwnL47BG7CmCWETM)

Сейчас для всех компонентов один экземпляр сервиса, то есть при нажатии на + изменяются все текстовые поля. Как сделать, чтобы, например, у первого и третьего компонента был свой экземпляр сервиса, у 2го и 4го свой, а у 5го отдельный от всех, как на картинке.

[image: Пример работы]

Comment: ты читал про dependency injection в angular? это же описано на самых первых этапах - как дать возможность компоненту иметь свой инстанс :(

Comment: @overthesanity да, читал, но не понятно, как это использовать в моем конкретном случае

Comment: что именно ты читал? =)

Comment: @overthesanity мне перечислить все ресурсы, что я прочитал? Вы можете помощь более конкретно, например, ссылкой или более конкретным ответом?

Comment: я ведь задал безобидный вопрос, зачем так реагировать?) судя по твоей реакции - ты не читал :) > `например, ссылкой или более конкретным ответом` - ссылка официальная документация angular.io

Comment: @overthesanity реакция вполне безобидная, просто не знаю, как еще реагировать на данный вопрос. Официальную документацию я читал. С angular раньше не работал, поэтому не могу понять, как это использовать в моем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Решение есть в документации https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

В сервисе уберите providedIn, укажите в декораторе компонента свойство:

```
@Component({
/* . . . */
  providers: [Service]
})
```

Почитайте про DI в angular

Comment: если убрать `providedIn` - то данную задачу > `Как сделать, чтобы, например, у первого и третьего компонента был свой экземпляр сервиса, у 2го и 4го свой, а у 5го отдельный от всех` нельзя решить только через локальные провайдеры компонента

Comment: @overthesanity нет, у каждого компонента будет свой экземпляр сервиса. Я даже специально проверил :) Об этом так же сказано в документации.

Comment: причем тут документация. > `у каждого компонента будет свой экземпляр сервиса`, а как сделать так чтобы у двух компонентов был один экземпляр?

Comment: @overthesanity а это было в вопросе? Мне кажется речь об этом не шла, возможно я не правильно понял. Да, вероятно, не так понял

Answer (score -2):

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection, 
https://habr.com/ru/post/429342/
вот вам конкретные ссылки, также советую почитать про синглтон классы, независимо относительно какого ЯП. В ангуляре все сервисы являются синглтонами - то есть для всего приложения создается один единственный экземпляр - и данный экземпляр инжектится в корневой компонент по умолчанию

```
@Injectable({
  // we declare that this service should be created
  // by the root application injector.
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

обратите внимание на данный кусок кода в вашем сервисе
P.S.: как я помню, инжект начали писать на 6 ангуляре, до этого сервисы надо было указывать в providers родительского модуля

Comment: так мне как раз и не нужно, чтобы был один экземпляр сервиса на все приложение. Необходимо, чтобы у разных компонентов на экране был свой экземпляр, который я укажу.

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю, насколько данное решение является верным.

Сделал ручное создание экземпляра сервиса для каждого компонента. Получаю список дочерних компонентов и в каждый добавляю новый экземпляр сервиса.

```
export class App {
    @ViewChildren('test') private tests : QueryList<A>;
    @ViewChildren('test1') private test1 : QueryList<A>;

    ngAfterViewInit() : void {
        let _countService : CountService = CountService.init();
        this.tests.toArray().forEach(test => {
            test._countService = _countService;
        });

        _countService = CountService.init();
        this.test1.toArray().forEach(test => {
            test._countService = _countService;
        });
    }
}
```

А в самом компоненте в `set` получаю новое значение и подписываюсь на изменение `count`.

```
export class A {
  private countService : CountService;

  public set _countService(_countService : CountService) {
    this.countService = _countService;

    this.countService._countSource.subscribe(
      (_count: number) => {
        this.count = _count;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: не является правильным вовсе, если у сервиса есть зависимости - то как ты вручную его создашь?

Comment: @overthesanity так подскажите тогда верный ответ

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

Comment: @overthesanity если я просто укажу `@Component({ providers: [CountService] })` то у каждого компонента будет свой экземпляр сервиса. А если мне будет нужно, чтобы у двух компонентов был одинаковый экземпляр? Как тогда?

Comment: позволь мне поинтересоваться зачем тебе в принципе такой велосипед?

Comment: Такое задание. Насколько я понимаю, экземпляр сервиса создается либо один для всех компонентов сразу, либо для каждого компонента отдельно?